# how to configure jasper report server "JAVA_HOME" in centos?

Tags: centos6, jasperserver, java-home

my java_home is (echo $JAVA_HOME >>
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.65.x86_64/jre)
when starting installing jasper report this warning is shown "WARNING: JAVA_HOME environment variable not found
[default]
"
thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

As I know Jasperserver doesn't support open jdk 1.7. But supported 1.7 and 1.6 ORACLE jdk and 1.6 OPEN jdk. Try to switch to 1.6 version.

Comment: thanks alot . but i use jre 1.7 and this problem solved.